# Office 365 Sharepoint in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer, office365, network-drive

I have the same issue as [this person here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/71991/office-365-sharepoint-access-denied-error-when-mapping-webdav) in getting a drive mounted as a network drive. Except I am working in the Windows 10 world. Do I still need to authenticate through Internet Explorer first, or is there a way with edge now that IE is the outdated browser.

Edit for clarity: I understand that it still is possible to use the method in the linked question to map a network drive (internet explorer internet options, the log in), but as IE is outdated and insecure, should it still be done this way? If not, what should we do instead.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between your problem and the linked question.  Have you tried the solution and simply used Edge instead to navigate to the URL?

Comment: Yes. I will add clarity to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the statement "IE is outdated" is coming from . It is still very much supported by Microsoft, and in some cases still necessary to run some workloads.

This is one such scenario. Using mapped network drives and using the "view in explorer" are supported only with IE10 and IE11.